# Creative commons link with HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-completed, ssl, footer, creative-commons

I just followed the [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) in the footer of (some) sites in the Stack Exchange network and wondered, why it is not linked with HTTPS.

Creative commons has [a valid certificate](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), so why not link to HTTPS instead?

- https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/

Comment: I think they forgot that link in making things protocol relative. There are more links in that footer that switch to http.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We're going to be spending time finishing the TLS support after a few current projects, but this is a simple and reasonable request: it'll be in the next build.

Comment: Next build > rev 2016.1.22.4112 (MSE) or > rev 2016.1.22.3206 (sites)

Comment: @Nick Craver Cool! :)